# Java eclipse I want to open the form like tab

Tags: java, eclipse

Java eclipse: I want to open the form as shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0wT5.png

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make your program look like that? With tabs? If that's the case, use a tabbed pane.

link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html